# Getting alternative columns to have text on top in css

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a page where I have image 1 on top and the text at the bottom and image 2 at the bottom and the text on top. I'm not sure how to go about doing it this way.

In my JSFIDDLE I would like "Text 1" to be at the bottom. "Text 2" on top and "Text 3" at the bottom.

my html

```
<div class="gallery_wrapper">
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QuLaaLb.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_title">
    <h2>
      Text 1
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vFEg6ef.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_title">
    <h2>
      Text 2
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery_image">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QuLaaLb.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_title">
    <h2>
      Text 3
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6e6mwpuy/)

Comment: Can you provide css so that we can look after it.

Comment: I like to do this using an unordered list then you can use the :nth-child(odd) pseudo selector.

Comment: SET margin-bottom/margin-top to 0 in each h2 you want to change.

Comment: put the first h2 tag above the first div.gallery-image tag

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started. You can use flex and pseudo-properties to achieve this.

```css
.gallery_wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.gallery {
  background: #333333;
}

.gallery:nth-child(even) {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.gallery_title {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery_wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vFEg6ef.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_title">
      <h2>
        Text 1
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vFEg6ef.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_title">
      <h2>
        Text 2
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery_image">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vFEg6ef.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_title">
      <h2>
        Text 3
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` for your requirement.
In  `flexbox` there are two properties with which you can solve your issue. Either using `order` or using `flex-direction`. But `flex-direction` is for `parent` and `order` is for child. So you can use any of the properties to solve your problem.

In this example snippet, I use `order`.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.text {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.image {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://files.allaboutbirds.net/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/images/blue-winged-warbler.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.item:nth-child(2n) .text {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="text">Text 1</span>
    <span class="image"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="text">Text 2</span>
    <span class="image"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="text">Text 3</span>
    <span class="image"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following `CSS` to achieve this.

```
.gallery{
  position: relative;
}
.gallery_title{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.gallery:nth-child(even) .gallery_title{
  bottom: auto;
  top: 5px;
}
```

Check the link here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e6mwpuy/2/)